# Is there a better way to pass many arguments to a controller's constructor and avoid too many arguments or initialization

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I read in one of the answers here in SO that *Java Swing* isn't fully in **MVC** pattern. I'm also new with using the **MVC** pattern and I code in *Java Swing*. I'm trying to find a solution or a way I can minimize the number of "`this`" keyword during initialization or assignment of values to fields.

For instance, say I have the ff. `JPanel` with many `JComponents`

```
//View
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
private final JTextField1 jtf1;
private final JTextField2 jtf2;
....
..
private final JTextField30 jtf30;

    private void initControllers(){
        jtf1.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(jtf1,jtf2......jtf30));
    }

}

//Controller
public class MyActionListener implmements ActionListener{

private final JTextField1 jtf1;
private final JTextField2 jtf2;
....
..
private final JTextField30 jtf30;

    public MyActionListener(JTextField1 jtf1,JTextField2 jtf2,..JTextField30 jtf30){
        this.jtf1 = jtf1;
        this.jtf2 = jtf2;
        ........
        this.jtf30 = jtf30; //Does this mean I have to have 30 of "this" assignment?
    }
}
```

Or I thought maybe if I pass the entire `JPanel` view **MyPanel** and generate `getters()`, would be correct or better?

Like this:

```
public class MyActionListener implmements ActionListener{

private final JTextField1 jtf1;
private final JTextField2 jtf2;
....
..
private final JTextField30 jtf30;

    public MyActionListener(JPanel myPanel){
        this.jtf1 = myPanel.getJtf1;
        this.jtf2 = myPanel.getJtf2;
        ........
        this.jtf30 = myPanel.getJtf3; 
    }
}
```

What is the common practice of resolving tens of view components that you need reference? 
Can you give advice on how to correct this? I doesn't look appropriate to have too many arguments to constructors. I want to clean the code.

From how I understand what I read about MVC is that, the controller class can accept both **Model** and **View** as arguments in its `constructor` as in

```
public class MyController implements xListener{
private final Model model;
private final View view; 

    public MyController(Model m, View v){
       this.model = m; //to access getters or setters
       this.view = v; // to access getters or setters
    }
}
```

Making `MyController` dependent to `Model m` and `View v`, if that's correct.

I'd appreciate any suggestions

Thanks.

Comment: Technically, you don't need `this` in your constructors, it's useful for when the field is the same name as the parameter or from a reading point of view, but something like `model = m` in your `Controller`s constructor would work just fine

Comment: Having had to deal with these issue a lot, one thing I've found is it's better to focus on a view as been a single unit of work.  That is, you don't expose the other UI elements which make up the view and instead, focus on representing the model requirements in what ever way the view wants to and interact with the controller/view via one or more defined `interface`s which describes the expected contractual functionality.  This would mean, in your `MyPanel` class, it would be responsible for managing the fields itself. I'm not sure I see the point of `MyActionListener`

Comment: You might also like to learn how to use arrays or `JTable` for managing a large number of "similar" components

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your suggestion. I just put `JTextField` to serve as an example. But in the project I'm working on has many different JComponents including `JTable` etc. The form has too many UI components which controls other UI components within the same panel as well.

Comment: MVC is fun - repeat, it will become true.  Basically, in a "pure" sense, the controller is the glue between the model and view, it controls all interactions between them and neither should know about each other. That can sometimes be more work then it's wroth as the complexity of the model increases, you'd end up duplicating a bunch of functionality. This is where Swing "blurs" the line, allowing the view to share the model

Comment: Also, a view may contain or be a controller for other views ... fun times ;)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time for a full reply, however: about a listener, if it's not a general purpose one, just use a (named) nested class in your panel, to let listener view and access panel's instance variables. For general purpose ones, you need to work on general behaviurs. As example, if you need to enable (or disable) all jTextField, just iterate on components added to container and check for instanceof jTextField. Of course performing operations on GUI needs a better approach (for example, panel must send the list of JTextField to the listener and listener just iterate over this list)